# In v12 angular material how to get colors from custom theme in any sass file

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, themes

I followed the very last angular material 12 guide to create my custom theme and it works well, and I also succeed to create a custom style file for components, for example to overload button styles by adding a different background color on :hover.

My problem is I couldn't find a way to SIMPLY refer to a color of my pallette in a component sass file as we could do by declaring a variable in the styles.sass project root style file:

styles.sass:

```
:root
  --color-primary-hover: #007bc7 
  --color-primary: #005e98
```

then in any component sass file:

```
.my-class
   background: var(--color-primary)
```

Obviously I could it this way, but then I have to maintain my colors in two distinct files, in the root styles.sass file and in my-theme.scss file where I defined my whole palette.

I also tried the opposite, to define my palette colors in the root styles.sass file, and then in my-theme.scss file to create my palette referring to the root colors but I couldn't make it work:

my-theme.scss

```
$my-palette:(
  ...
  500: var(--color-primary) // instead of 500: #005e98
  ...
)
```

**How can I refere to a color of my palette in a simple way without the heavy way of customing a full component?**

my-theme.scss file:

```
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;
@use './app/shared/custom-styles/button.style.sass' as button;

@include mat.core();

// my custom palette
$back-office-palette: (
  400: #007bc7, // Primary hover
  500: #005e98, // Primary blue
  800: #142733, // Darkest blue  
  A400: #ffe800, // Orange accent hover
  A500: #ffcf00, // Orange accent // accent green tetradic #76E04E
  contrast: (
    400: #ffffff, // White (contrast of primary hover)
    500: #f2fcff, // Lightest blue (contrast of darkest blue)
    800: #f2fcff, // ????? maybe white
    A400: #472c00, // Contrast for yellow accent
    A500: #472c00  // Contrast for orange accent
  )
);

$back-office-theme: mat.define-light-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: mat.define-palette($back-office-palette, 500),
      accent: mat.define-palette($back-office-palette, A500),
      warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette)
    )
  )
);

@include mat.all-component-themes($back-office-theme);    
// Custom back-office styles
@include button.theme($back-office-theme);
    
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
```

Example of a full component customisation with button.style.sass:

```
@use 'sass:map'
@use '~@angular/material' as mat

@mixin color($back-office-theme)
  // Get palette from back-office-theme
  $color-config: mat.get-color-config($back-office-theme)
  $primary-palette: map.get($color-config, 'primary')

  // custom primary button with hover
  .bo-primary-button
    background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($primary-palette, 500)
    color: mat.get-color-from-palette($primary-palette, 200)
  .bo-primary-button:hover
    background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($primary-palette, 400)
    color: mat.get-color-from-palette($primary-palette, 100)
    
@mixin theme($back-office-theme)
  $color-config: mat.get-color-config($back-office-theme)
  @if $color-config != null
    @include color($back-office-theme)
```

root style file styles.sass

```
// Palette colors duplicates
:root
  --color-primary-hover: #007bc7 // 400
  --color-primary: #005e98 // 500
  --color-dark-background: #142733 // 800
  --color-accent: #ffcf00 // 800

*
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  box-sizing: border-box

ul
  list-style: none
```

Answer (score -1):

So to access your theme color from anywhere, moves the :root declaration in the my-theme.scss file:

```
// First declare your colors in variables 
// (all colors you need, not only the one in the palette, 
// like for a green success buttonfor example)
$my-success: #408526; 
$my-primary-hover: #007bc7;
$my-primary: #005e98;
$my-primary-dark: #142733;

// Then use these variables to define your palette:
$my-palette: (
  50: #ffffff,
  100: $my-primary-hover,
  200: $my-primary,
  900: $my-primary-dark,
  contrast: (
     ...
  )
);

// Then declare the global variables using the first $ variables:
:root {
  --my-success: #{$my-success};
  --my-primary-hover: #{$my-primary-hover};
  --my-primary: #{$my-primary};
  --my-primary-dark: #{$my-primary-dark};
}
```

Then, you can refer to your defined colors in any component sass file, my-component.sass:

```
.my-class
  background: var(--my-primary-dark)
```

Comment: awful solution. You need to extract data from your theme variable with `mat.get-color-config($my-theme)`

Comment: Hello @Sampgun, could you, please, share a example? I.E. how to get the primary color in a basic component scss and use it in html? Thx 